# Are there access right differences between these two ways of creating an InputStream?

Tags: java, inputstream, file-access

I recently dug up some old code for reading data from files. It created an Input stream like this:

```
InputStream stream = 
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filepath);
```

`filepath` is a String here. This worked fine, for local files, but when trying to read files accessed on a shared network drive, I'd get an error saying the stream was closed.

I created a File object instead, and created the input stream like this instead:

```
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Now it works perfectly. But I got very curious. It was suggested when I had my original line of code, that the file simply did not exist. But switching to the second line of code, it clearly does. Are there any restrictions to access rights with the first approach? What is the difference between them? Why can only the second one access the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're not doing anything clever with Custom Class loaders, the `getResourceAsStream` method on the classloader will use the same rules for loading the resource as it does for loading classes: it will only load files present on the classpath.

The fact you're getting `null` means the file you're loading is not on the classpath. That it's a shared network drive is a red herring.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks a lot. Now I also know what a red herring is ;). Got confused there for a second :)